# fpdi - Add content to the existing pdf but the existing content is moving out

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf, fpdi

I am using fpdi to add content in the existing pdf file that has some contents already. Once I added content, the existing content is moving out (The length of the pdf file is increasing). Please help me to fix this.

```
$pdf =& new FPDI();
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->setSourceFile($filename); 
$tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1); 
$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 0, 0, 0, 0, true); 

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'My content abc',0,2);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'My content2 abc',0,2);
$pdfGeneration=$pdf->Output('F',$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'mypath/newwrited.pdf');
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added the parameter, po

```
$pdf->AddPage("P", "Letter");
```